# WHY does it write into firebase on mount and not on click it react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I have a function that when is called on click it will write into firebase, trying for hours but not success. I would like to write into FB on click and not on mount here is my code.

Home.js

```
render() {

    return (

      <SideMenu
        menu={menu}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onChange={isOpen => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
          <Button onPress={this.storeHighScore('9', 'Hello world')} // < HERE
                buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(30, 144, 255)', borderRadius: 10 }}
                textStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
                title="Add" />
        </View>
      </SideMenu>
 );
  }
       //it should call this function on click
       storeHighScore(num, value) {
        firebase.database().ref('notes/'+num).set({txt :value});
      };
     }
```

I'm calling firebase config in login page which is called before home

Login.js

```
componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAk34kU_Ei6m_J5f_qGXFJivG0bzFhV-pA",
        authDomain: "hotelsystem-876ae.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://hotelsystem-876ae.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "hotelsystem-876ae",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "414932466185"
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use like this

```
<Button onPress={() => this.storeHighScore('9', 'Hello world')}
```

This way onPress will wait for the arrow function inside of it to be called (by your press action) to then trigger the storeHighScore.
If you don't instance the function, then storeHighScore will be called just after it renders.

Hope it helps